# Returning the following season and year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, window-functions

For a particular season and year when it started I have to get the following season and year when it starts, e.g. for Summer 2021 I should get Autumn 2021, and for Winter 2021 I should get Spring 2022.

"Seasons" table has the "Order" column which indicates the order of seasons in a year, so it looks like this:

| SeasonID | Order | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Spring |
| 2 | 2 | Summer |
| 3 | 3 | Autumn |
| 4 | 4 | Winter |

*Remark: "Order" column may seem redundant, but this is actually simplified/adapted version of the problem I have, where "Order" column is neccesary.*

I have a stored procedure that has @Year and @SeasonID as input parameters. I have to get following season/year in @FollowingSeasonID and @FollowingYear parameters, which I use later in the stored procedure. I'm not sure if I've used the best technique for that:

```sql
(...)

    DECLARE @FollowingSeasonID int;
    DECLARE @FollowingYear int;
    if object_id('tempdb..#Years') is not null drop table #Years
    CREATE TABLE #Years ([Year] int)
    INSERT INTO #Years ([Year]) VALUES (@Year), (@Year + 1)

    SELECT @FollowingSeasonID = FollowingSeasonID, @FollowingYear = FollowingYear
    FROM
        (SELECT SeasonID, 
                [Year], 
                LEAD(SeasonID) OVER (ORDER BY [Year], Order) AS FollowingSeasonID,
                LEAD([Year]) OVER (ORDER BY [Year], Order) AS FollowingYear
        FROM Seasons
        CROSS JOIN #Years) t
    WHERE SeasonID = @SeasonID AND [Year] = @Year

(...)
```

Is there a better way to do that? Could it be achieved in just one query?

I need those values in multiple stored procedures/views/... so I wanted to extract that part of code if a function. Scalar valued function can't return two values, so I have to create a table valued function (and I have to use table variable instead of temp table #Years). However, is there a better way to do that instead of having a table valued function that always returns just one row?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood, given a single `seasonId` you just need the following Id and reset it to 1 and increment the year if necessary?

```
declare @seasonid int=1, @Year int=2021

select  FollowingSeasonID, @Year + yr FollowingYear
from (
    select *,
        IsNull(Lead(SeasonId) over(order by [order]),1) FollowingSeasonID,
        case when Lead(SeasonId) over(order by [order]) is null then 1 else 0 end yr
    from seasons
)s
where SeasonId=@SeasonId
```

If you don't want to use a TVF you could just use this as a view/cte, joining on currentId and return the followingId and `yr` value to add to your current year.

Comment: SeasonID and Year are given. It's not that I _don't want_ to use TVF, I was just wondering if it is the right way, because it seems weird that I have to return the whole table to get just two integers. I think that I can't make this a view because I don't know what to put in "Year" column (I could put not year, but the number to increment year, just like you are doing, but it would be much better if I would directly get the year).

Comment: I don't see why you can't make it a view that just returns a value to add to your existing value for year - maybe supply an actual use-case example - are you using it with individual parameter values or joining to a table etc?

Comment: If I have such "unadjusted" data - one column means the actual value I should use, and another means the value I should add - it increases probability that I will forget it and make a mistake... that's the main reason. For now, I use it just with individual parameter values as in provided example, but actually I will sooner or later need it in joins and then I will have to use the solution you suggested...

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this code in UDF and you should be able to get seasonId, year

```sql
DECLARE @season table(SeasonId int, SeasonOrder int, Name varchar(10))
INSERT INTo @season values
(1,    1    ,'Spring')
,(2,    2   ,'Summer')
,(3,    3   ,'Autumn')
,(4,    4   ,'Winter');

DECLARE @FollowingSeasonID int;
DECLARE @FollowingYear int;
DECLARE @year int = 2021, @SeasonId int = 2;

;WITH CTE_YearSeason AS
(
SELECT y,s.* FROM @season as s
CROSS APPLY
(VALUES (@year), (@year+1)
) as t(y)
), cte_ranking as
(
SELECT *, row_number() over (order by y,SeasonOrder) as rnk 
FROM CTE_YearSeason)
SELECT SeasonId, Y as year 
FROM  cte_ranking as c
where c.rnk = (SELECT c1.rnk 
from cte_ranking as c1
where c1.SeasonId = @SeasonId and c1.y = @year) +1
```

| SeasonId | year |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021 |

Comment: Thanks for answer, the part I was missing was `(VALUES (@year), (@year+1)) as t(y)`... With than change, the version I posted seems simpler than this one. Btw. why do you use CROSS APPLY, isn't CROSS JOIN enough in this case?

Comment: @petra, yes. you can use CROSS JOIN, in place of CROSS APPLY here.

Comment: @petra, yes. your version looks simple.